# Jquery - Issues wrapping a <span> to each array value dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi folks I have a quick question. With the help of experts on this forum I was able to get a simple timesheet application going. Everything works great. Im just trying to do one simple adjustment.

Here is the full code:
https://jsfiddle.net/tj6bcjos/9/

During this part of the code:

```
 rw = '<tr><td>'+p.ID+'</td><td>'+p.description+'</td><td>'+
  s.join('<br>')+'</td><td>'+e.join('<br>')+'</td><td>'+h.join('<br>')
  +'</td><td>'+n.join('<br>')+'</td></tr>'
```

This part in particular: `h.join('<br>')`. I tried changing it to `h.join('<span class="Hours"></span><br>')` I was expecting this to return something like `<span class='Hours'>(amount of hours)</span><br>` but instead getting `(amount of hours)<span class='Hours'></span><br>`.

I understand now that its not the way the .join function ouputs the data. So I figured I try `.join('<span class="Hours">')h.join('</span><br>')` but no luck either. Basically I just want every entry in the h array to return `<span class='Hours'>(amount of hours)</span><br>`. Been scavenging for answers on different forums but seems like I might need to recode this part.

Curios to if you guys have a different approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

and what about that?

```
'<span class="Hours">' + h.join('</span><br><span class="Hours">') + '</span>'
```

Comment: Wow, dont know how I missed that. That worked as expected. Thank you so much lem :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `map`:

```
h.map(function (text) {
  return "<span class='Hours'>" + text + "</span><br>"
})
```